# What kind of ball is used in the FIFA World Cup?

Tags: football, equipment, world-cup

What are the specifications, the FIFA World Cup football needs to have?

I'm looking for weight, size, flight and possibly more info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FIFA regulations on the ball are found in [FIFA 2014/2015 Laws of the Game (PDF)](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf), Law 2:

> LAW 2 - THE BALL
>
> Qualities and measurements
>
> The ball is:
>
> - spherical
> - made of leather or other suitable material
> - of a circumference of not more than 70 cm (28 ins) and not less than 
>     68 cm (27 ins)
> - not more than 450 g (16 oz) and not less than 410 g (14 oz) in weight at 
>     the start of the match
> - of a pressure equal to 0.6 – 1.1 atmosphere (600 – 1,100 g/cm<sup>2</sup>
>     ) at sea 
>     level (8.5 lbs/sq in – 15.6 lbs/sq in)

These are the general regulations for any ball, whether or not it is used in the World Cup.

However, [as is the case with every World Cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3599/1723), they have developed a new ball to be used in this year's 2014 FIFA World Cup in Brazil.  It is the Adidas Brazuca:

[image: Adidas Brazuca]

The specifications for the Adidas Brazuca are:

- Six polyurethane panels
- 437 grams
- 69 cm circumference
- 0.2% water absorption
- 141 cm rebound
- 7% loss of pressure

Sources:

- [Gizmodo: Viva Brazuca](http://gizmodo.com/viva-brazuca-taking-the-2014-world-cup-game-ball-for-a-1475887755)
- [Daily Mail: The Science Behind the 'Brazuca'](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/worldcup2014/article-2641897/The-science-Brazuca-World-Cup-2014-ball-set-surpass-Jabilani.html)

Comment: Side note to anyone who is interested: Last World Cup, many of the goalies were extremely unhappy with the design because of the grips that were present on them. I had a chance to use one as well and agree. I was not able to get as good a handle on it. This ball also appears to have those grips, and it may have an impact on how well a keeper can perform in certain conditions.

Comment: Good answer, but you're missing "not more than 450 g (16 oz) and not less than 410 g (14 oz) in weight at
the start of the match". Strangely enough, this isn't on the FIFA web page you quoted, but is on page 15 of their Laws of the Game PDF: http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf